# What is the difference between putting the variable "top" inside for loop and before?

Tags: javascript, stack

```
var isValid = function (s) {
  let stack = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    let top = stack[stack.length - 1];

    if (s[i] === "(" || s[i] === "{" || s[i] === "[") {
      stack.push(s[i]);
    } else if (s[i] === ")" && top === "(" && stack.length !== 0) {
      stack.pop();
    } else if (s[i] === "]" && top === "[" && stack.length !== 0) {
      stack.pop();
    } else if (s[i] === "}" && top === "{" && stack.length !== 0) {
      stack.pop();
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return stack.length === 0;
};
```

Function like this works (this is the problem https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/)
However when i put variable "top" before the for loop ,the function doest do its job.
Can you please explain me what is the difference in this 2 cases?
Thank you!

I tried to put variable "top" before and in the for loop ,got different acting function.

Comment: Stack changes in the for loop so if you have top before the for loop, the value of top will not change as stack changes.

Comment: You might be interested in [this page on variable scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)

Comment: thank you for the answers! Regarding "imvain2" comment, now i understand it a bit better, but i still dont understand how so that "let stack" changes if he is outside the for loop?